# WorkSheet_Change to hide rows based on two cells and different Cases in a Select

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, worksheet

I frankensteined VBA code for `Worksheet_Change` to hide blank rows by looking at which option is selected from a data validation list.

It works for one data validation option.

The user has the option of two data validation lists.

- If they select on one (lets say $B$2) there may need to be 5 rows hidden and the other data validation is blank.
- If they select on the other (say $C$3) there may need to be 7 rows hidden and again the other data validation is blank.

I want it to look at two data validation ranges, if one is blank, look at the other and when the user changes the data validation entry it hides the blanks rows up to row 22. And vice versa on the other data validation list.

I am having trouble with the If Else Then and Case for multiple options.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Define Dims
Dim counter As Long
Dim iRange As Range
Dim AreaToHide As Range

Rows("13:22").Hidden = False

'Calculate book
Worksheets("Home").Calculate

'Case select view by pack
If Target.Address(True, True) = "$D$13" Then
        Select Case Target
                Case "Product 1", "Product 2", "Product 3"
                
'Find last row to hide for view by pack
With ActiveSheet.Range("E13:E22")
    'loop through each row from the used range
    For Each iRange In .Rows
        'check if the row contains a cell with a value
        If Application.CountA(iRange) > 0 Then
            'counts the number of rows non-empty Cells
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Next
End With

'hide blank rows for view by pack
Set AreaToHide = ActiveSheet.Rows(counter + 13 & ":22")
AreaToHide.Hidden = True
                                                                  
'Case select view by country
ElseIf Target.Address(True, True) = "$C$13" Then
        Select Case Target
                Case "Country 1", "Country 2", "Country 3"
                
'find last row to hide for view by country
With ActiveSheet.Range("G13:G22")
    'loop through each row from the used range
    For Each iRange In .Rows
       'check if the row contains a cell with a value
        If Application.CountA(iRange) > 0 Then
            'counts the number of rows non-empty Cells
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Next
End With


'hide blank rows for view by country
Set AreaToHide = ActiveSheet.Rows(counter + 13 & ":22")
AreaToHide.Hidden = True
        
            Case Else
                'Do nothing
        End Select
    
    End If
    End Function
    
   
End Sub
```

I get

> Else without IF

on

```
ElseIf Target.Address(True, True) = "$C$13" Then
```

Comment: That code can't compile as you are missing End Select.

Comment: Is that your question? You don't actually say if you have been getting error messages or another problem.

Comment: @SRJ Correct, the code gives me an Else without IF error on line "ElseIf Target.Address(True, True) = "$C$13" Then"

Comment: @SRJ apologies, do I need two End Selects? One after each select case statement? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following worked if anyone ever wants to know, I was missing a Case Else,
End Select in the first case section and didnt need the End Function:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Define Dims
Dim counter As Long
Dim iRange As Range
Dim AreaToHide As Range

Rows("13:22").Hidden = False

'Calculate book
Worksheets("Home").Calculate

'Case select view by pack
If Target.Address(True, True) = "$D$13" Then
    Select Case Target
            Case "Product 1", "Product 2", "Product 3"
            
'Find last row to hide for view by pack
With ActiveSheet.Range("E13:E22")
'loop through each row from the used range
For Each iRange In .Rows
    'check if the row contains a cell with a value
    If Application.CountA(iRange) > 0 Then
        'counts the number of rows non-empty Cells
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next
End With

'hide blank rows for view by pack
Set AreaToHide = ActiveSheet.Rows(counter + 13 & ":22")
AreaToHide.Hidden = True

Case Else
End Select

                                                              
'Case select view by country
ElseIf Target.Address(True, True) = "$C$13" Then
    Select Case Target
            Case "Country 1", "Country 2", "Country 3"
            
'find last row to hide for view by country
With ActiveSheet.Range("G13:G22")
'loop through each row from the used range
For Each iRange In .Rows
   'check if the row contains a cell with a value
    If Application.CountA(iRange) > 0 Then
        'counts the number of rows non-empty Cells
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next
End With


'hide blank rows for view by country
Set AreaToHide = ActiveSheet.Rows(counter + 13 & ":22")
AreaToHide.Hidden = True
    
        Case Else
            'Do nothing
    End Select

End If
  

End Sub
```